# What is a good way to develop images or templates that can be used on Xen, KVM and EC2?

Tags: virtualization, amazon-ec2, xen, kvm-virtualization

I want to make images to do simple network services (e.g. serve a web app, run a memcached, or whatever). It would be really nice to develop an image once, test locally, and then be able to deploy it to different hosts (e.g. EC2, Linode, local KVM)... is this presently possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at Red Hat [BoxGrinder](http://boxgrinder.org/) project, it does have plugin to target most of the cloud platforms.  But, it is limited to RH based OSes...

[Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) is another way to do this, but with a little steeper learning curve, but more flexibility...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot help having to build the golden image on a single platform. From there on, it's only a matter of having the conversion tools, like virt-v2v for example.

I would simply prepare the template on the most commonly targeted platform, since a more popular platform will have the less popular ones building conversion tools for